# Self-intersected curve and knot curve

Tags: knot-theory

I am new to knot theory. So the following problem description may not be rigorous; but I will try my best to explain intuitively. Please tell me if there is ambiguity.

For any self-intersected curve $S$ on the XY plane, is it always possible to find a corresponding non-self-intersected knot curve in 3D such that its projection on the XY plane is exactly $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. For example if you have an infinity of self-intersection it is not possible.

But as long as your curve is not too much pathological, yes. If you have a "reasonable" parametrization from $S^1$ to $S$, what you can do is consider the corresponding parametrization $s : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and create a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by constructing the curve $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 : a \rightarrow (S(a).x, S(a).y, a)$, we now just need to close the loop by adding the segment $(S(0).x, S(0).y, [0,1])$ (for that you need $S(0)$ not to be an intersection).

A short remark on your question: it is important to see that a knot is never self-intersecting. (At least if we consider standard knot theory where singular knots does not exist)

Comment: But a singular knot is self-intersected.

Comment: You are right, but they are not considered as knot in "standard knot theory" where a knot is an embedding. In this case the injectivity imposes that there is no self-intersection.In any case, the construction I gave you produces a knot that is never self intersected (As long as S(0) is not an intersection, but it is always possible to be in such situation). I will edit my respond to add the case of singular knots

Comment: What do you mean by "reasonable" parametrization? For any given self-intersected curve on a plane, then is it possible that such kind of parametrization always exists? Can you kindly point to any mathematics references? Thank you!

Comment: By reasonable I mean smooth. And no, it does not always exist for any loop. For example if we take the Hilbert curve (and if we link the extremities), there exists no smooth parametrization of this loop from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$. What I said is that **if there exists a smooth parametrization** of your loop $S$, then you can create a knot with it. The procedure I gave you creates a smooth embedding from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (once you smoothed the connections at $(S(0).x, S(0).y, 0)$ and $(S(0).x, S(0).y, 1)$) which is the definition of a knot. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/knot